# looking for a search tool that reads data from DB and index

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

currently i have a requirement to read the new feeds in DB and index into a search tool. i understand that logstash-elastic search combo will work here. we have to input the DB plug in and the same will be indexed to elastic search.
but i am looking for other better options, if any, to do some research. any suggestions please?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for an specific tool to index data from a DB into the search index then you might be interested in Solr's [DIH](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler).

It can work with other sources (files, rss...but DB is it's forte). Very handy for small to medium size indexing. If you need to index many millions of docs it starts to get trickier (possible, but trickier, as parallelizing stuff is not stragihforward).

In ES land there is [elasticsearch-jdbc](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc), similar to the DIH but not built in. I have used it too and it works. And a bit less user friendly for a quick setup imho.